# NSDateFormatter not formatting dates correctly when adding events to calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ekevent

I am having trouble figuring out how to parse a certain date format using NSDateFormatter and putting it into an EKEvent.  At the moment this is my code.  I have already requested permission to add events and method is called from the completion handler of requestAccessToEntityType:completion:

```
-(void) performCalendarOperation {
    NSString *startString = @"04/28/2013 2:30 PM";
    NSString *endString = @"04/28/2013 5:30 PM";

    EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
    [newEvent setCalendar:[self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

    newEvent.startDate = [format dateFromString:startString];
    newEvent.endDate = [format dateFromString:endString];

    NSLog(@"START:%@\n\nEND:%@\n\n", newEvent.startDate, newEvent.endDate);
}
```

The NSLog prints the following:

START:2013-04-28 21:30:00 +0000
END:2013-04-29 00:30:00 +0000

In this particular case I want this to be 12 hour time

The NSDateFormatter format string appears to be correct for this style of date string, but for some reason the output is incorrect. The event is actually added to the calendar later on in the code after setting some more properties, but that isn't important to this question.
Just as a note, I never encountered this problem when I was parsing dates pre-iOS 6.0, so maybe it is an artifact of some change in the API or formatting that I'm not accounting for?  Are there any obvious mistakes that I'm just not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the way NSLog prints NSDate objects. Your format string is just letting the date formatter know what form your string is in so it can convert it to a date. If you want it to print out in a different way, then you need to log a stringFromDate: string, not the NSDate object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLog always prints in 24h and timezone GMT+0/UTC.  That's why it looks incorrect, but it actually is.  If you want to use NSLog to print date correctly you need to use a NSDateFormatter to format the date to your liking (using stringFromDate).

Comment: That appears to be the problem, and an obvious one at that.  Thanks for saving me even more of a headache!